# macOS Big Sur 11.1 can't find stdlib.h w

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, developer-tools, macos-big-sur

I am in my build folder of my cpp project and want to compile
`make`
and as a response i get

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:97:15: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not
      found
#include_next <stdlib.h>
```

also I can't compile in Clion either.

I tried to set differnt paths with `xcode-select -p`  and the sdk packages isn't avaible anymore.

Comment: setting the `SDKROOT` environment variable might help

Answer (score 0):

If you recently updated to Big Sur, you will need to re-run `xcode-select --install` to re-install the XCode Command Line Tools (also available via https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

If you end up with a library path issue, the following may help:

```sh
_sdk_root=`xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path`
export LIBRARY_PATH="${_sdk_root}/usr/lib"
```

This sets the LIBRARY_PATH to the appropriate system `/usr/lib` XCode would use.

Similarly, adding `-I${_sdk_root}/usr/include` (you'll still need the above `_sdk_root=` line) may help your compiler find the appropriate header.